# Evaluar una sucesión numérica como valor booleano

Tags: lista, haskell, booleano

En la consola de Haskell quiero evaluar si lo que afirma de una sucesión de números es verdadera o falsa.
Ejemplo:
Si a Haskell le pregunto lo siguiente: En la sucesión (o lista de números), que va de 1 hasta 100, todos los números de dicha sucesión si se los divide enteramente entre 10 dan como resultado 9, lo cual es falso (`False`), que es lo que tiene que responder Haskell.

Para preguntarle esto a Haskell, intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
[n | null [n | n <- [1..100]], not (n `div` 10) == 9]
```

Pero Haskell tira error con este mensaje:

```
<interactive>:7:2: error: Variable not in scope: n
<interactive>:7:41: error: Variable not in scope: n :: Bool
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás haciendo un lío con tanto paréntesis y llaves.

Lo más simple es usar la función `all` para comprobar que el *predicado* se cumple para toda la lista:

```hs
all (\n -> not (n `div` 10 == 9)) [1..100]
```

Fíjate que el `not` se aplica a toda la igualdad, no sólo al primer término como tenías. Se puede hacer mejor si en lugar de aplicar `not` simplemente compruebas que no sea igual:

```hs
all (\n -> n `div` 10 \= 9) [1..100]
```

Tal como lo querías hacer, habría que aplicar `null` a la comprensión de lista de este modo:

```hs
null [n | n <- [1..100], not (n `div` 10 == 9)]
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, el tercer código que es el más parecido al que positié es el que más me sirve.

Comment: Tengo otra duda, ¿cómo puedo modificar el código para preguntarle a Haskell para que en lugar de que evalúe si todos los elementos cumplen con cierta propiedad, evalúe en cambio si existen elementos en la lista que cumplen con cierta propiedad?

Comment: Encontré una página ¿cómo se usa el operador any?

Comment: `any` sería la pregunta contraria de `all`: `any (\n -> n `div` 10 == 9) [1..100]` daría `True` si hay algún elemento en la lista que cumpla la condición. (o sea, `all` es como `not . any` con el chequeo inverso)

Comment: Yo para preguntar si existen elementos que cumplían con cierta propiedad escribía any [n | n <- [1..100], not (n `div` 10 == 9)] pero tira error. ¿cómo sería esta pregunta bien formulada en Haskell con este formato?

Comment: `any` tiene como argumentos un _predicado_ y una lista. Tal como lo aplicas, sólo pasas una lista. Lo que puedes hacer es comprobar que esa lista está vacía: `not.null [n | n <- [1..100], not (n div 10 == 9)]`. Ya que da igual qué valores tiene, puedes usar booleanos: `and [not (n div 10 == 9) | n <- [1..100]]`

Comment: Bien entendido. Pero ¿Haskell no tiene ninguna palabra clave para existe? ¿siempre para preguntar por algunos Hay que usar not.null o any?

Comment: En haskell, hablar de  _existencia_ entra en lo filosófico. Un conjunto vacío sigue siendo un conjunto (aunque no contenga elementos) y además tiene un tipo de dato (eg: lista vacía de enteros). Yendo más allá, es posible que algo funcione mal y no termine con un resultado. Y aún así tendrá un tipo: _bottom_. La existencia está más relacionada con el tipo de dato que con el valor en sí. Aunque sqrt (-1) no exista como número real, existe como complejo. Dicho todo este rollo, la palabra `exists` se relaciona con los _Tipos Existenciales_, mejor usar otra cosa.

Comment: Acá vengo a contestar y resolver dudas de programación, no ha hacer filosofía, este sitio no tiene nada que ver con la misma, ni es mi intención hacer filosofía. Lo de "existe" viene porque en lenguaje ISetL existe una palabra clave exist que se usa para evaluar si hay al menos un elemento de la lista que cumple con cierta propiedad. Si deseas seguir ayudándome (te lo agradecería) tengo otra duda aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599534/crear-una-lista-mayor-como-resultado-de-la-primer-parte-de-la-lista-original

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado. Cuando se usan _cuantificadores existenciales_, sea ISetL o haskell, tiene más relación con el sentido de _"pertenencia"_ a un grupo o conjunto que al hecho de que "exista" en el sentido ontológico. En haskell esa relación de pertenencia se establece desde el sistema de tipos. Por otro lado, la programación haskell y la filosofía tienen casa común en la lógica y la teoría de categorías. Que no se hable de ello en este sitio no quiere decir que no sea parte importante de la programación haskell.

Comment: Tengo otra duda. Si quieres ayudarme adelante.