# Crear dos listas de igual cantidad de elementos añadiendo ceros según sea necesario

Tags: lista, haskell

Lo que tendría que hacer es crear dos listas a partir de dos listas dadas, igualándolas en cantidad de dígitos añadiendo ceros a la izquierda en la primera o segunda lista según sea necesario.

Primero defino el tipo de dato ListInt, que se refiere a una lista de enteros de la siguiente forma

```
type ListInt = [Int]
```

El siguiente paso es definir la función `clonar`

```
clonar :: Int -> a -> [a]
clonar n x = map (const n) [1..x] -- esto está andando bien
```

Ahora la función que está andando mal

```
padZero :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (ListInt, ListInt)
padZero l1 l2 | length l1 < length l2 = ([clonar length l2 - length l1, l1 0], l2) 
              | length l2 < length l1 = (l1, [clonar length l1 - length l2, l2] 0)
              | otherwise = (l1,l2)
```

Si hago esta prueba tira error

```
main = print(padZero [9,9] [1,0,0,2])
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
padZero [9, 9] [1, 0, 0, 2]
```

Resultado:

```
([0, 0, 9, 9], [1, 0, 0, 2])
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
padZero [1, 0, 0, 2] [9, 9]
```

Resultado:

```
([1, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 9, 9])
```

Comment: Por un lado, `padZero` recibe tres argumentos `Int`, pero la estás llamando con sólo dos y además listas de enteros en lugar de `Int`. Por otro lado, estás invocando a la función clone con 4 argumentos. Supongo quieres poner algo así: `clone 0 (length l2 - length l1) l1`. Para aclarar lo que quieres, ¿puedes poner algún ejemplo con el resultado final?

Comment: Dale, lo pruebo y te digo. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ya que el código está con error tampoco entiendo muy bien lo que se pretende hacer.
Acá encontré dos páginas que pueden orientar para dar una idea de lo que pretende implementar http://www.java2s.com/ref/javascript/javascript-string-padzeros-length.html
http://www.java2s.com/ref/javascript/javascript-string-padzeros-length.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La llamada a `padZero` no es coherente con su signatura. `padZero` espera 3 argumentos `Int`, pero se le está pasando dos listas de enteros, `[Int]`. Por lo que logro intuir, lo que se quiere es igualar las dos listas en longitud añadiendo ceros a la izquierda.

La signatura sería así:

```hs
padZero :: [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
```

o tal vez así

```hs
padZero :: ([Int], [Int]) -> ([Int],[Int])
```

Señalar que el paso de una versión a otra es lo que se conoce por *currificación*, para lo que podemos usar las funciones `curry` y `uncurry`:

```hs
padZero' :: [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
padZero' = curry padZero
```

Un modo sencillo de crear esta función es como función recursiva, añadiendo ceros a la lista más corta hasta que las dos listas tengan la misma longitud:

```hs
padZero :: ([Int], [Int]) -> ([Int],[Int])
padZero (xs, ys) | length xs < length ys = padZero ( 0:xs, ys   )
                 | length xs > length ys = padZero ( xs,   0:ys )
                 | otherwise = ( xs, ys )
```

Para hacer una versión más similar a la pregunta, tenemos que crear una lista de ceros para añadir a la lista más corta.

Para crear una lista de ceros de una longitud dada no necesitamos crear una función nueva, ya que tenemos disponible la función `replicate`.

El código quedaría algo así:

```hs
padZero :: ([Int], [Int]) -> ([Int],[Int])
padZero (xs, ys) | nlen < 0 = ( zeros ++ xs, ys   )
                 | nlen > 0 = ( xs, zeros ++ ys )
                 | otherwise = ( xs, ys )
  where nlen = length xs - length ys
        zeros = replicate (abs nlen) 0
```

Se calcula la diferencia de longitudes, `nlen`, y según sea, elegimos añadir una lista de ceros a un argumente u otro.

Comment: Ahora entendí, estaba ingresándolo mal: Tengo que poner padZero ([9,9],[1,0,0,2])
([0,0,9,9],[1,0,0,2]), entre paréntesis y coma entre las dos listas.

Comment: A partir de la función clone, implementé la función replicate, invirtiendo el orden de ingreso de los datos.

Comment: Cualquier código que te pueda ayudar, dentro de lo que entiendo, te ayudo, y gracias de nuevo.